# Problem with Exponentiation assignment and array.Reduce

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm trying solve a test. But i got a problem when method Reduce give me a wrong answer.
Here i'm need check `371 = 3**3 + 7**3 + 1**3`  and i got 347 like `3 + 7**3 + 1**3.` Why i get wrong accumulator in first call ? Why Math.pow is wrong while item * item * item is true in this case ?

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
  let array = value
    .toString()
    .split("")
    .map((item) => parseInt(item));
  console.log(array); // [a, b, c, d, ... ]
  const length = array.length;

  let result = array.reduce((sum, item) => {
    return Math.pow(item, length) + sum;
  }); // [a**length + b**length + c**length + ....]
  console.log(result);

  return value == result;
}

narcissistic(371)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the initial sum value 0 in the reduce method.
As it is mentioned in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce),

> A function to execute on each element in the array (except for the first, if no initialValue is supplied).

So you have to pass an initial value to the reduce method so that it executes the given method on each item including the first one.

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
  let array = value
    .toString()
    .split("")
    .map((item) => parseInt(item));
  console.log(array); // [a, b, c, d, ... ]
  const length = array.length;

  let result = array.reduce((sum, item) => {
    return Math.pow(item, length) + sum;
  }, 0); // 0 should be the initial sum
  console.log(result);

  return value == result;
}

narcissistic(371)
```